# XML transformation without building a DOM

Tags: java, xml, sax

Do any of Apache's (or other) Java libraries include an implementation of org.xml.sax.ContentHandler that simply generates the XML indicated by the SAX events?

Preferably, this would be done in a class which is customizable either through open source code, extensibility, or hooks for adding behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the clues.  It may be a week before I can get my head back into this part of the code.  I'll accept an answer after I research them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that if you have a `SAXSource` and a `StreamResult` and perform an identity transformation, you basically get what you want (although hidden behind quite impenetrable code). This is my interpretation of the question title, anyway.

```
TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer().transform(source, result);
```

Comment: Following through with this clue, I found this:

[link](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/usagepatterns.html#sax)

I think this is on the track I wanted.  I'll accept this and ask a related question now. :)

Answer (score 0):

Does `org.apache.xml.serialize.XMLSerializer` (available in the standard JDK as `com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serialize.XMLSerializer`) cover your needs?